# DetailTables in RadGrid not expanding

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I basically have a RadGrid and inside the RadGrid is a DetailTable. Now the DetailTable does not expand, but when I debug the DetailTableDataBind event I see that there is data assigned to the DataSource. If I comment out everything in the DetailTableDataBind then the DetailTable expands but obviously wont have any row data since I had commented out the event. Basically I want the DetailTable to show a column that was used inside the RadGrid, which in this case is the "Comment" column.

Why when I try and assign a DataSource that the DetailTable wont expand?

Here are some snippets of code.

The aspx page

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
        <AjaxSettings>
            <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="MemberCommentsGrid">
                <UpdatedControls>
                    <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="MemberCommentsGrid" />
                </UpdatedControls>
            </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </AjaxSettings>
    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>


<telerik:RadGrid ID="MemberCommentsGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
     AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" ShowStatusBar="true" OnDetailTableDataBind="MemberCommentsGrid_DetailTableDataBind" Skin="WebBlue">
    <ClientSettings AllowExpandCollapse="true">    
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView AllowMultiColumnSorting="true" DataKeyNames="MemberCommentID">
        <Columns>            
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MemberCommentID" HeaderText="Comment ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Comment Text">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DateAdded" HeaderText="Date Added">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserID" HeaderText="Comment Created By">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>       
        </Columns>
        <DetailTables>
            <telerik:GridTableView Name="MemberCommentsGrid" DataKeyNames="MemberCommentID" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Full ID">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Full Comment">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
            </telerik:GridTableView>
        </DetailTables>
    </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

The cs page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region Getting DataTable data
        string memberName = string.Empty;                       

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["MemName"] != null)
                memberName = Request.QueryString["MemName"].ToString();
            else
                Response.Redirect("../Account/Login.aspx");



            using (AcquirerPortal.Data.MemberComments mc = new AcquirerPortal.Data.MemberComments())
            {
                dtMemberComments = mc.GetMemberComments(Members.GetMemberIDByMemberName(memberName));
            }


        }
        #endregion

        MemberCommentsGrid.DataSource = dtMemberComments;
        MemberCommentsGrid.DataBind();
    }

    protected void MemberCommentsGrid_DetailTableDataBind(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DetailTableView.DataSource = e.DetailTableView.ParentItem["Comment"].Text;
    }
```

If there is a better way of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: have you looked at the Telerik site to see any of the examples that they have on their website..?

Comment: I have had a look, but it seems like I am following the correct way unless I am doing something stupid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the comment field needs to be cast to a list first?

Comment: Why would this field need to casted to a list? What the Comment field in the RadGrid is what I want to display in the DetailTable, basically I am expending the view of a Comment in the DetailTable.

Answer (score 0):

Alright the reason behind this was the DetailTable's Name was the same as the RadGrid's ID. I just changed the name of the DetailTable and now it works.

Comment: If you found your answer, then you should mark this as the accepted answer (the green check mark).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of expanding the detail table on the RadGrid.

```
// expand all of the rows on the page

int counter = 0;

int NoOfRows = Pages.PAPage.ApptsTableGrid.Rows.Count;

for (i=0;i<NoOfRows;i++)

{ 

    HtmlTableRow gRow = Pages.PAPage.ApptsTableGrid.Rows[counter + i];

    foreach(HtmlTableCell gCell in gRow.Cells) 

    {    

        if(gCell.CssClass=="rgExpandCol")

        { 

            gCell.MouseClick();  

            ActiveBrowser.RefreshDomTree();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 

        }  

    }

    counter++; 

}
```